# Select distinct values from two different columns of two tables with other non-distinct columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, distinct-values

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate rows from an Access dataset made up of two tables. I want to retrieve the distinct values from one column of two tables, but also retrieve the values of other columns of duplicates and unique values.

The field I want unique values for is [PART-SN] from table2. I want to select all other fields from table1 and [PART-SN] from table 2, of which all rows should be returned for all distinct rows of [PART-SN]. [PART FIND NO] and [PART-ATA-NO] have equivalent values and has duplicates. I've seen posts on how to get values from two tables of the same column. Is there a way to join the two tables to get this result?

Sample data (not actual data):

Table 1:

```
ID  BOM_PART_NAME  PART FIND NO  POS  LCN  POS_CT   
1       E              0001       1    P0    1
2       A              0002       1    P1    1
3       C              0003       1    P2    1
4       D              0004       1    P3    1
5       F              0005       1    P4    1
```

Table 2:

```
ID  PART-ATA-NO    PART-SN     PART-NAME
1      001                         A
2      002                         B
3      003                         C
4      004          1100           D
5      005          1101           E

ID  BOM_PART_NAME  PART FIND NO  POS  LCN  POS_CT   
1       E              0001       1    P0    1
2       A              0002       1    P1    1
3       C              0003       1    P2    1
4       D              0004       1    P3    1
5       F              0005       1    P4    1
```

Table 2:

```
ID  PART-ATA-NO    PART-SN     PART-NAME
1      001                         A
2      002                         B
3      003                         C
4      004          1100           D
5      005          1101           E
```

What I'm getting:

```
ID ... PART FIND NO       POS       PART-ATA-NO   PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
3        003              1           003          1101  
3        003              1           003          1102
4        003              2           003          1101
4        003              2           003          1102
5        004              1           004          1101
5        004              1           004          1102
```

Desired Result:

```
ID    PART FIND NO       POS      PART-ATA-NO     PART-SN
1        001              1           001          1369
2        002              1           002          1444
3        003              1           003          1100
4        003              2           003          1101  
5        003              3           003          1102
6        003              4           003          1103
7        003              5           003          1104
8        004              1           004          1105
9        004              2           004          1106
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. Could you give us a minimal table definition with keys and everything? Are [PART FIND NO] and [PART-ATA-NO] UNIQUE columns, PRIMARY KEY columns, FOREIGN KEY columns or anything? Also, did you come up with some not-yet-complete solutions or parts to a solution? That would be helpful because I really try to understand what you wanna do!

Comment: You should post your data structure and what you have tried so far.

Comment: They may be Foreign Key values since the two columns are equivalent values.

Comment: PK for now in both tables is just ID (Access default).

Comment: The query I originally ran to merge the two tables:

SELECT table1.ID, TABLE1.BOM_PART_NAME, TABLE1.CII, TABLE1.[PART FIND NO], TABLE1.CSN, TABLE1.AFS, TABLE1.EQP_POS_CD, TABLE1.LCN, TABLE1.POS_CT, TABLE1.SERIAL_NO, TABLE1.PART_NO_LLP, table2.[PART-ATA-NO], table2.[PW-PART-NO]
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON TABLE1.[PART FIND NO] = table2.[PART-ATA-NO];

Answer (score 0):

Open up Access and click on create new query
It will prompt you to select the tables you want to include
Once you have them selected, if they dont already have relationship lines between them, drag/drop  the matching fields to create the relationships
Then click on the Sigma symbol to turn on groupings option
Drag the fields you want included down to the area where you set up the output for the query
Then select which fields you want to group by and which fields are the expressions you are trying to get the values for
Run the query and see if you get the results you want
If you dont, fiddle with the options until you get the output you want
Then click the dropdown for the Design/Run button and there will be a SQL option
Click that and it will show you the select statement you want to use

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique values for  [PART FIND NO] and [PART-ATA-NO] you can try to do an UNION.

```
SELECT Table1.[PART FIND NO]
FROM Table1 UNION SELECT Table2.[PART-ATA-NO] As [PART FIND NO] From 
Table2;
```

It's a bit weird, but I have done a test in Access 2016 with values repeated in Table1 and Table2 and even values appearing twice in a Table and the Union only returns the values once.

```
|Table1|
|AAA|
|BBB|
|CCC|

|Table2|
|AAA|
|BBB|
|AAA|
|DDD|

|Query 1|
|AAA|
|BBB|
|CCC|
|DDD|
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It is not weird, but by design that UNION returns only unique rows.  If you want the UNION to return all rows, including rows that produce non-unique values, use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the overall question is a duplicate of [How do I merge two tables in Access while removing duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615587/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-in-access-while-removing-duplicates)

But here is a query specific to your needs.

EDIT:  Updated second query to remove Table2.[PART-SN] to eliminate duplicates of merged tables after more information from original poster.

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.[PART-ATA-NO], Table2.[PART-SN]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[PART FIND NO] = Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]

UNION

SELECT Table1.*, Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[PART FIND NO] = Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]
WHERE (((Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]) Is Null))

UNION

SELECT Table1.*, Table2.[PART-ATA-NO], Table2.[PART-SN]
FROM Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[PART FIND NO] = Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]
WHERE (((Table1.[PART FIND NO]) Is Null));
```

It is likely not possible to fullfil all requirements in one query.  The results of one query can feed another query.  It is possible to use a saved (i.e. named) queries in the FROM clause of another query (or if in design mode it means you can show and join to other queries just like tables).  If eliminating duplicates is the primary concern, then save your modified UNION query (like above), for example named as [Merge1and2].

Assuming that [Merge1And2] now contains only unique [PART FIND NO], you can do something like

```
SELECT [Merge1And2].[PART FIND NO], Table2.[PART-SN]
FROM [Merge1And2] INNER JOIN Table2 ON [Merge1And2].[PART FIND NO] = Table2.[PART-ATA-NO]
```

This will give you all the [PART-SN] values for each unique [PART FIND NO].  Of course the results of this second query will no longer show unique [PART FIND NO] values, since the same number can potentially be listed for each [PART-SN] -- at least according to what you commented about [PART-SN] having multiple values per [PART-ATA-NO] in Table2.

If your ultimate goal is to merge the two tables, removing duplicates, BUT you have multiple related values like [PART-SN], then from the information I have you will need more than one table:  First a primary table to store the unique part numbers, then a one-to-many relationship on a second table for storing duplicate [PART-SN] (and possibly other) values.

Comment: The query didn't work, but that's because the PART-SN's are duplicating too. When I remove that field, the duplicate values for PART FIND NO and PART-ATA-NO are removed. However, I need the PART-SN's. I'm trying to understand the logic of this query. What about it ensures distinct values for the two fields, and how could I apply this logic to the PART-SN field as well? Thanks.

Comment: I tried a third UNION where the PART-SN of table2 is Null with a Left Join on table2, but that didn't change the result.

Comment: First of all, you say "third" union but you describe what is listed as the "second" union in the sample code I gave. Either way, what you say tells me that one table is completely matched by INNER JOIN, so that there are no non-matching rows in that table. Unless you post example data showing contrary information, I can only trust that the queries work. You can also run each of the SELECT statements separately to investigate.  You can also run various COUNT queries on the UNION results to see if all counts add up to the same counts as the original tables... a little double checking.

Comment: Sample data:

`ID     PART-FIND NO    PART-ATA-NO              PART-SN
1               001                       001                              101
2               002                       002                              110
3               003                       003                              120
3               003                       003                               130
4               004                       004                               120
4               004                       004                               130`

Comment: Basically, the PART-SN is repeating for each set of matching PART FIND NOs. When it moves on to the next PART FIND NO, it's the same PART-SN. It's not the correct PART-SN.

Comment: It's best to edit and improve the original question rather than posting details like this in comments.  I can't quite tell what these numbers are to represent.  You can format them better in columns.  But you need to show sample rows from each table separately and then explain what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: It looks like it should work, though. The two union statements take the place of a full join in Access (Full Join is not supported by Access), and UNION should return only unique rows. The inner join returns the matching rows of the PART FIND NO and PART-ATA NO columns (these might be FK elements). I forgot to mention that PART-SN does contain null values as well.

Sorry, by "third" union I meant I just added another UNION statement. However, it's not just the UNION clause that's supposed to output non-duplicate values.

Comment: I think I only need unique PART-SN's actually. Sorry for the confusion. Looking at my data sets again, it seems there will be duplicate PART FIND NO's and PART-ATA-NO's. There are identical PART FIND NO's and PART-ATA-No's which is to be expected. I'll update the question again. I still need the other columns, but they can be duplicates. Just PART-SN needs to be unique.

Comment: Yes, the INNER-UNION-LEFT-UNION-RIGHT pattern with appropriate constraints (my answer) is equivalent to a FULL OUTER JOIN.  Technically, a FULL OUTER JOIN is possible with just a LEFT-UNION-RIGHT pattern with the null condition excluded in the WHERE clause of the LEFT join. As for your statement about non-duplicate values, the goal is to get non-duplicate matches so the UNION statement should be sufficient.  Otherwise I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I personally am willing to help... 'cause I'm a nice guy. But just to warn you, Stack Overflow is designed for well-formatted, specific questions. Of course it is okay to edit things and improve things, but it is not for extended debugging issues. You will find that most other users will simply down-vote your answer and move on. Make sure that you explore the problem and understand what you need before posting. Although you edited your question, you  still did not provide a complete, well-formatted example of your data AND the results you expect. Nobody will help further if you don't do that.

Comment: Another hint... code like SQL statements should usually be included in the question also (edit if you need), along with a statement of what the problem is and any relevant data examples.  The SQL code is useless if you don't state what the issue is.

Comment: I added some sample data from the two tables, but the two tables have many columns so I only included it a few to keep it brief (and only so many fit on a single line).

Comment: Well, you're going to hate me for this, but removing solely duplicate SN's isn't going to work because there are multiple null values in the set. So actually, your solution earlier addresses the actual problem. I tried the merged query sample you posted. It only gives the [PART FIND NO] and [PART-SN]. Any tips on how to expand it to include the other columns in the set? Thank you so much for your patience and assistance.

Comment: I'll have to look at this later... but for now if you want other columns, just add them to the SELECT list.  It seems to me that you're still exploring the data and looking for an answers without a precise question.  The fact is, you can either end up with multiple tables, all perfectly normalized with appropriate relationships, so that there are technically no "null" values in your tables.  That is probably preferred, but might be more complex that you imagine. Or, you can have results with duplicate values for some fields and null values in other fields.  But ultimately it is up to you.

Comment: There will be null values in PART-SN column as not all SN's have been loaded into the table. It's a work in progress, and not all under my control. I want unique PART SN's for each PART FIND NO, but null PART SN values each have a unique PART FIND NO.

Comment: I still recommend multiple normalized tables--tables with non-null key values and which have proper foreign keys and indexed relationships. It's always possible to reproduce rows with duplicate keys and null values from normalized tables--just write a query that joins them however you want. But as you are experiencing now, it's difficult to get unique keys from a bunch of tables with duplicate data and undefined relationships. In other words, 1 table for unique [PART FIND NO] and corresponding fields, another table for unique [PART SN] , then another table that relates them, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's another problem. The PART FIND NO's and PART ATA NO's in the original table also contain null values. Since we have to join those two columns, that might be causing issues.

Comment: But my co-worker needs all the data. I'm trying to find a way to make that possible, but it really is not a complete data set.

Comment: Some problems are not "programming" problems.  If you have key fields that have null, then you need to discuss with your co-workers what to do in those case, or at least warn them.  Setting up multiple tables does not have to loose data, but can at least merge matched records, eliminate duplicates, etc. All the data can be there if you set it up correctly.  There is nothing else this question/answer can help with since it has demonstrations various UNIONS and JOINS that you will need.  It is up to you to add additional columns, etc.